# How do I select a certain word with its result in a sentence with in a column SQL?

Tags: sql

I am new to SQL and I am trying to learn on the job. I need to filter out the confidence level for responses in a table. The column doesn't not only include the confidence it includes the whole answer. I only need for the answer where it says type:2 I in fact just need the number. 
 I couldn't past a table here so one column is question the second is volunteer the third is answer in Answer there is whole jumble of words and markers I only need where it says type. In fact i only need the number that follows type `/"type/":2`
 here is what the line in answer looks like what I need is in bold

```
 {
     "decision": "default_unused",
     "rateorskip": "rate",
     "decision_extra": "{ \"segments\": [{\"start\":0,\"end\":9,\"text\":\"the **\"type\":2**,\ series)\",\"commerceEntityExtraInfo\":[]}]}",
     "skip": "valid"
 }
```

This is what I wrote:

```sql
SELECT
    question,
    volunteer,
    answer
           (CASE WHEN answer "type/"= 2 THEN "HIGH",
           WHEN answer "type/"= 1 THEN "MEDIUM",
           WHEN answer "type/"= 0 THEN "LOW"
           ELSE "SKIP/NO TARGET"
           END) AS 'volunteer confidence'

FROM blanla
```

It gives me this error line 5:36: mismatched input '"type/"'. Expecting: '%', '*', '+', '-', '.', '/', 'AT', '[', '||',

I also tried:

```sql
SELECT
    question,
    volunteer

    IF EXISTS(
        SELECT
            answer CASE
                WHEN answer 'type' = 0 THEN "High"
                WHEN answer 'type' = 2 THEN "Medium"
                WHEN answer 'type' = 3 THEN "Low"
                ELSE "Skipped/No Target"
            END
     ) AS VolunteerConfidence
FROM blanla
```

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms)

Comment: you are showing JSON not a table -- are you sure that is what the data looks like?

Comment: your json also looks wrong -- could you post the actual json and not one that is edited with the `**`

Comment: It is My SQL and pesto.

Comment: Yes the answer looks like that in the table  I don't know why.

Comment: Yes here you go :

Comment: {
  "decision": "default_unused",
  "rateorskip": "rate",
  "decision_extra": "{\"segments\":[{\"start\":12,\"end\":27,\"text\":\"Carlos Bejarano\",\"fbid\":\"0\",\"type\":0,\"title\":\"https:\\/\\/es.wikipedia.org\\/wiki\\/Carlos_Bejarano\",\"fbtype\":\"\",\"commerceEntityExtraInfo\":[]},

Comment: Is it possible to help me with this?

Comment: So does any one know how this might work?